# Rewrite one-line if - "?:" as "??" - to avoid StyleCop warning

Tags: c#, if-statement, stylecop

How to write a oneliner "if" using "??"

example: How to write the following using "??" instead of "?:"

```
        SiteSettings = (sitessettings == null)
            ? UnityManager.Instance.Resolve<ISiteSettingsFactory>().Get(100)
            : sitessettings;
```

Comment: It's always easier when using the correct terms - see [Conditional (`?:`) Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), and the links to `??` or "null-coalescing operator".

Comment: Was this a speed typing test?

Comment: @Kevin, no it is just a question that I couldn't figure out. How did it not meet the question cafeterias that you voted it down?

Comment: @user3311522 I didn't vote it down.  I gave all the answers +1 and noticed they were all answered within a minute of each other.  I didn't mean that the question shouldn't have been asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conditional statement is equivalent to:

```
SiteSettings = sitessettings 
            ?? UnityManager.Instance.Resolve<ISiteSettingsFactory>().Get(100);
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
SiteSettings = sitessettings ?? UnityManager.Instance.Resolve<ISiteSettingsFactory>().Get(100)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this?

```
SiteSettings = sitessettings ?? UnityManager.Instance.Resolve<ISiteSettingsFactory>().Get(100)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SiteSettings  = sitessettings ?? UnityManager.Instance.Resolve<ISiteSettingsFactory>().Get(100);
```